# How can I read a file in apache webserver using java?

Tags: java, apache, file

I have a computer with working apache webserver, my URL 
is (ejemplo.com/number.txt) (in my local network).

I am trying to read these files using java with another computer (running in windows) but I have the error:

> File not found.

I can access all files if I use chrome.

Errors:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\ejemplo.com\6645.txt (El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos).

```
 public void read(double[] measures, int position) {

            long inicio = System.currentTimeMillis(); //comenzamos a cronometrar//
            int numero_caracteres = 0;
            int variable;
            BufferedReader br = null;
            Random random = new Random();
            variable = random.nextInt(get_numero_ficheros_totales() - 1); //numero aleatorio donde vamos a empezar a leer//
            char caracteres[] = new char[get_longitud_fichero() + 999]; //equivalente a 8 KB//sirve para concatenar los caracteres leidos//

            for (int i = 0; i < get_numero_bloques_lectura(); i++) {

                int desde = (variable) + i;

                if (desde >= ((get_numero_ficheros_totales()))) {
                    desde -= get_numero_ficheros_totales();
                }

                try {

                    StringBuilder concatena = new StringBuilder(); //para concatenar caracteres//
                    String fichero = url+ desde + ".txt";
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fichero);
                    br = new BufferedReader(fr); //leemos el contenido de ese fichero (por dentro)
                    numero_caracteres = br.read(caracteres, 0, MedidorAbstracto.get_longitud_fichero());

                    if (numero_caracteres != -1) {

                        concatena.append(caracteres, 0, numero_caracteres); //concatena desde 0, hasta la numero_ficheros_totales del fichero que tenemos(controlamos
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    System.out.println("Error: Fichero no encontrado");
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println("Error de lectura del fichero  " + i);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                } finally {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("Error al cerrar el fichero");
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint at String fichero = url+ desde + ".txt";
do you see the correct file name ?

Comment: i solved the problem, finally I use class url conecction and it`s working. thanks!